# System.Speech and Dictation

Tags: c#, winforms, speech-recognition

Here is what I am doing. I have a program that goes with my usual speech. I have noticed that MS Speech lacks a lot from under development. So I am taking the system.speech and reusing it to build my own speech platform.

I have had success by adding words to a text document by using if statements. However, I am really don't want to do if statements for over 400,000 words. So my question is, Since the dictionary of words is in a text file. How would I query the dictation to the text file? the below code is using if statements.

```
 private void Dictation_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        string speech = e.Result.Text;
        if (speech == "hello")
        {
            result_textBox.AppendText(speech);
        }
        if (speech == "my")
        {
            result_textBox.AppendText(speech);
        }
        if (speech == "cat")
        {
            result_textBox.AppendText(speech);
        }
        if (speech == "is")
        {
            result_textBox.AppendText(speech);
        }
        if (speech == "hungry")
        {
            result_textBox.AppendText(speech);
        }
        if (speech == "for")
        {
            result_textBox.AppendText(speech);
        }
```

This is just a few words I put in to test. When I say the words, they appear and in accurate timing. However, I have noticed that a word is not picked up here and there. They also are not spaced. they look like this in the rich text box (mycatishungryfor). So if I decide to use if statement which works how would I space them out and would using a text file to hold the words. Would the looping process through the text file take so long that it would miss words that is being said.

This is being done in winform. C# language and I have also done research with different approaches and I am not sure wether to use a database, iList, Dictionary or text file.

SO if I was to change my approach which would be a better route to go. I only want to MS Speech for the word sound wave clips, so I don't have to record each word.

Comment: Why do you need if-statements? What's wrong with `string speech = e.Result.Text; result_textBox.AppendText(speech + " ");` ? Apart from the trailing space.

Comment: I did not think of that let me try it real quick

Comment: add each word to an array maybe and have it read from there? and like @Blorgbeard said, use the `(speech + " ");` for the spaces.

Comment: it still works the same and the words come out as (hellomymyisisforforianthirdisis) and my test file has these words hello
my
cat
is
hungry
for
ian
third 
base
front                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    I said as a sentence straight thru

Comment: `result_textBox.AppendText(speech + "");` does not space it out

Comment: Where all the words are not spaced if you notice it skips a word here and there. So it is not really putting all the words I say. Is this because of the time it takes to loop through the txt file

Comment: it does space it out, I forgot to put a space in between the " ". So it still come to my question. as I am speaking it still does not pick up every word

Comment: You need to modify the question to clarify it better then. Speech recognition is not expected to be 100% accurate.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev the question does not need any modifying. I am sorry that you are unable to understand the question. It is clear and to the point. If you cannot understand what was said then move on to the next question. As far as the comments, they answered my question. So modifying the question would just be confusing to others. However, you probably would not understand the question even if I did modify it. I never asked how to make it 100% accurate. I asked which would be better to use a text file, ilList or Dictionary. What do you not understand out of that, its perfectly clarified.